# How to a fetch detached Git HEAD from a local repository?

Tags: git, git-fetch

During a `pre-commit` hook (actually a `ref-update` in Gerrit) the repository is in a detached HEAD mode (witch is fine).

Doing a `git clone path/to/my/repo` does clone/fetch this commit, but I'd like to just do a `git fetch` and avoid cloning my repository each time there is a commit (for various reasons like avoiding to change file time stamps each time).

Doing a `git fetch --all` on a previously cloned repository (like above) does *not* fetch this detached head commit. Note that I **do** have the commit's **SHA1** but a `git checkout commit-sha1-here` doesn't work either since it hasn't been fetched.

I do know it's by design that only remote branches are fetched, but since *clone* can fetch detached heads, isn't there a way to update my cloned repository to retrieve them later? I'd like to **avoid having to create a temporary branch** each time just for that.

The final goal is to have an updated work-tree of a bare repository (detached HEAD).

Comment: If you run `git ls-remote` you'll see that the fetch-er can *see* the fetch-ee's `HEAD` (so it's definitely possible in theory).  In practice, simply listing `HEAD:<something>` as a refspec should work, but I haven't tested this.  You can either pass this as a command line refspec, or update the `fetch` setting for the given remote(s).

Comment: @torek However all my attemps to fetch fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

`git pull` of a detached HEAD seems not allowed by design but a `git push` of that detached HEAD is possible (i.e., instead of fetching from the receiving side you push from the sending side):

```
$ git push <repository> +<sha1>:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Then from the repository receiving it:

```
$ git checkout <sha1>  # same as origin/master
```

Note: Pushing to `refs/remotes/origin/master` instead of pushing directly to `master` is disallowed by default if it's the current branch or a non-base repository, so we push to the origin reference.